# How to replace DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping in spring 5 programatically

Tags: java, spring

I have an application using Spring 3 and I am in progress to upgrade it.

I have faced a problem regarding DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is deprecated.

```
 private void findResources() {
        Map<String, Object> handlerMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping annotationMapping = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
        annotationMapping.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        annotationMapping.initApplicationContext();
        handlerMap.putAll(annotationMapping.getHandlerMap());

        BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping beanMapping = new BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping();
        beanMapping.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        beanMapping.initApplicationContext();
        handlerMap.putAll(beanMapping.getHandlerMap());

        this.urls = findUniqueUrls(handlerMap.keySet());
        this.defaultResources = findMethods(handlerMap, this.urls);
        this.jsonResources = new ArrayList<ResourceInfo>();
        for (Iterator<ResourceInfo> iterator = this.defaultResources.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            ResourceInfo info = (ResourceInfo) iterator.next();
            if (info.getUrl().endsWith(".json")) {
                iterator.remove();
                this.jsonResources.add(info);
            }
        }

    }
```

how to replace this findResource method?

also I have this part:

```
 HandlerMethodResolver resolver = new HandlerMethodResolver();
            resolver.init(handlerType);
```

HandlerMethodResolver is removed also.

Comment: What is it this code tries to do? Feels like a hacky way of obtaining something.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you,  trying to use this code in HomeController.java, it's an example taken from here: https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-resources/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/util/HomeController.java#L167

Method: findResource

Comment: I'm not asking where you are using it but what it is trying to achieve. If you want the list of urls I would suggest taking a look at Spring Boot, which does expose that information in the actuator endpoints.

Comment: @M.Deinum, exactly we are using this method to get the list of urls, can you provide me more information about what can I use from spring boot? thanks

Comment: I'm not saying you can use anything from spring boot, but you can look at the spring boot actuator project for inspiration. There is an endpoint exposing all urls in the app, which you could mimic.

Comment: You will also have to drop deprecated `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` in favor of the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`